# replace default index logstash-* with custom indexes in Jhipster Console

Tags: jhipster, elastic-stack

We are using jhipster console to visualize our application logs. I just changed the logstash config to send logs to different indexes based on environment Dev, sit etc. Now the dashboards are broken as they are using the default index logstash-*. Is there a way to pass in the index names as command line arguments when starting up docker containers to replace logstash-*. Also what is the best way of visualizing multiple indexes in dashboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [index pattern is hard-coded in dashboard definitions](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-console/blob/master/jhipster-import-dashboards/dashboards/default/dashboard/circuit-breaker-dashboard.json#L7), just edit their definitions and import them which basically means: clone the jhipster-console git repository, customize it by duplicating dashboards per index and build your own docker image.

Comment: I saw that, but just wondering if that can be replaced by a environment variable in docker compose files. I am still a starter with ELK. So I am not sure if its the right way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: No it cannot be customized with env vars for now but you can open an issue to request this feature.